# What is the field theoretic analogue of the Hamilton-Jacobi Equation?

Tags: field-theory, hamiltonian-formalism

Just as classical Hamiltonian Mechanics can be generalised to Hamiltonian Field theory, I was wondering if there is a field-theoretic analogue of the Hamilton-Jacobi equation, and if so, what is it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The generalized positions $q^j$ are replaced with fields $\phi^{\alpha}({\bf x})$;
[Hamilton's principal function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi_equation) $S(q,P,t)$ is replaced with a functional $S[\phi,\Pi,t]$; while the [Hamilton-Jacobi equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi_equation)
$$ H(q,\frac{\partial S}{\partial q},t) +\frac{\partial S}{\partial t} ~=~0$$
is replaced with
$$ H(\phi,\frac{\delta S}{\delta \phi},t) +\frac{\partial S}{\partial t} ~=~0.$$